# Why date.toString() twice to print the same result

Tags: java, date

When I call the method `date.toString()` twice, I have the same result, even though there is a two second interval. I think the second time should be 2s more than first time.

Program for example:

```
Date date = new Date();
System.out.println(date.toString());
System.out.println("----------");
Thread.sleep(2000);
System.out.println(date.toString());
```

The output is

```
Sat Oct 17 17:54:39 CST 2015
----------
Sat Oct 17 17:54:39 CST 2015
```

Comment: `Date` just contains the time that it was initialized to. It is not a clock, it just represents a particular Date/Time.

Comment: Why do you think the timestamp stored in `date` should change?

Comment: By the way, in Java 8 and later the old java.util.Date class has been supplanted by the new [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework. Specifically for this Question look at the `Instant` and `ZonedDateTime` classes.

Answer (score 4):

Quoting the Javadoc of the constructor of [`Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Date.html#Date--) (emphasis mine):

> Allocates a Date object and initializes it so that it represents the time **at which it was allocated**, measured to the nearest millisecond.

As such, the `Date` that is printed is the date when the object was created. Since you are printing the same `Date` object, it will be the same output.

```
Date date = new Date();
System.out.println(date.toString());
System.out.println("----------");
Thread.sleep(2000);
date = new Date(); // instantiate a new Date here
System.out.println(date.toString());
```

Output on my machine:

```
Sat Oct 17 12:09:16 CEST 2015
----------
Sat Oct 17 12:09:18 CEST 2015
```

Answer (score 0):

try this...

```
Date date = new Date();
System.out.println(date.toString());
System.out.println("----------");
Thread.sleep(2000);
date = new Date();
System.out.println(date.toString());
```

just initiate again the "date" before print for the second time